# Self-toggling ZigBee switch

Tags: home-automation, smart-switch

I'm trying to automate my home. I bought a few Ikea ZigBee bulbs, some switches and a ConBee II. I'm still figuring this out.

The Ikea switches look like this:

[image]

One thing I miss about regular rocker switches is that they move up and down, and you can look at their state to see whether the light is on or off. Of course, with ZigBee lights it's not trivial because multiple different switches can toggle the same light.

**Is there a ZigBee switch that can physically move itself on or off depending on whether the light is on or off?**

To clarify, I'm looking for a battery-powered switch that doesn't connect to my apartment's electricity.

Comment: This is a shopping question which is, unfortunately, off topic because the answer can/will change rapidly. I strongly recommend that you hit up some of the ZigBee forums, and particularly the support forum for whatever software you're using to drive the automation. Most that I've been to have _tons_ of hardware info, and if you can't find what you need already listed there, they'll be happy to point you in the right direction.

Comment: What you're looking for is a contradiction in terms. As soon as you go to smart controls, it becomes impossible to have a physical switch handle mean anything at all.  I mean literally, you'd be talking about having servo-motors inside the switch physically push the switch handle up and down (like Boeing's auto-throttle, *but not Airbus's*).   That would never sell at large scale, and would be a boutique product, so economies of scale would never pull the price down to consumer friendly levels. Figure $100-200.

Comment: "having servo-motors inside the switch" Are you sure that's the simplest way to toggle a switch?